# Visual analytic with graphs, maps etc from my user data?

Tags: php, mysql, reporting, analytics

I have lot of data stored about my users and now I can build user analytics from this data to provide meaningful data back to my users. I can output this as normal text which is ok but I want to display bargraphs, charts, world maps, etc...

So the question is how do i take all the data from my tables and add in all these graphs /maps? Do i need some software packages or do i need to "code" the graphs/maps? If software packages then are there any open source I can use?

The data saved includes user logs like visits, browsers etc along with lot of business activity details so i want to show my users like top 10 clients, top countries they came from, top products, top customers etc.

My platform is: MySQL and codeignitor PHP. 
I do not have a data wearhouse built but that can be done once i have a plan for how I can output all this data visually so it looks good.

Comment: pChart will handle pretty much any graphing you need done. As far as I know it doesn't do maps, however.

Answer (score 3):

your choices are vast and almost limitless. Assuming you don't want to write your own library, consider the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) or the [rGraph library](http://www.rgraph.net/) I use rhraph a bit more but fellow coders prefer the Google Chart API...

Comment: I dont mind writting my own or using something open source to write it. Prefer not to use Google or 3rd part APIs, As mentioned below, my dev team mentioned penthao but that is a much larger task for now. Need something smaller to take all the data and keep updating it in n real time

Comment: I use rGraph. Yes technically it's a 3rd party API, but only in the sense that it's already written. you install all the js files locally and have full control over them. I hacked into the rgraph meter files a bit myself to get a behavior to work the way I wanted it to produce...

Comment: Can this be used for mapping too? I dont see any maps like a world map brokwn down by countries so i could show top countries with numbers of customers for my users. Or do i need to write that code myself?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to write code that generates dynamically updated analyses?   or are you just trying to conduct the analysis over a set time period and 'post' it so that your users can view the results of the analysis? For the latter, you need is a statistical package (like R or even Excel if you want it quick and dirty).  For the former, you are going to need an API (like Google Chart).

Comment: I am trying to provide analytics to my users based on a set of metrics broken down into about 20 different reports. Ofcourse it needs ot be updated constantly because they are using the system daily. I dont want to use Google or 3rd part APIs, need it to be 100% in-house developed or using frameworks. My dev team mentioned penthao but that is a much larger task for now. Need something smaller to take all the data and keep updating in real time so whenever users run reports the data is up to date.